# There is a question mark in my prestashop window. It wasn't there before

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I just opened my store today. Before hosting firm directed my domain name to my IP there was no problem. 
When I the site is activated some people wanted to change some links. I did that in a hurry maybe that caused an error. Later when I check my site I saw a big question mark on the right. I put all of the files back from my backup but the problem still exists. Is there anyone who can help me?

Thank you 
FERDA
[image]

Comment: What does Chrome F12 tools say about it?

Comment: I don't know that tool :( How will I use it ?

Comment: Press F12, click on the magnifying glass, click on the object you want to inspect, and it will tell you where in the DOM it is and give you hints as to where it came from.

Comment: It shows this line <body id="cms" class="  cms-index-index cms-home" data-twttr-rendered="true">

Comment: This f12 tool looks like very useful. It shows some missing files. I will share the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing image. Whenever an image (products, categories etc) is missing in prestashop, this question mark image is shown. It is 404.gif (or any other image format) placed in the img folder of the prestashop.

There may be two reasons to this issue:

1) At header section, it seems like you have a missing image (i think one of the social icons). This is the recommended case. Please check your images. I think it is one of the icon for social images.

2) This may be not the reason, but whenever there is some problem in the paths for images, prestashop display the 404 or question mark image. But it seems like paths are fine as other images are shown.

**Proposed Solutions** : First check in F12 tool (dont know what is it called :P ) that specific element i.e. right click on that question mark image and then select the Inspect Element, you will have the F12 tool opened. Check there and share the HTML code. Also please share some code before and some after that, so that it can be easily checked.

Comment: This was a hard day :) I used the F12 tool. It is interesting I was running this web site for test for a long time. There was no Question mark(no lost files) . When the domain name opended it is shown. It is interesting really. Thank you for your help.